# bash: running script on multiple directories simultaneously

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

Let's say that I have multiple directories: `nmg_1, nmg_2,..., nmg_5`.
Each of these directories contains two subdirectories: `fol, unf`.
In each of the subdirectories there is a text file.

So, I have this script: `run.sh`, that is to read a certain line of the text files in each subdirectory and output another file. Thus, I was wondering, is there a way to run the script in parallel, that is, for the script to be run in multiple subdirectories at once?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yup.  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What do you mean by *in* multiple directories?  A process can only have one current directory at once, although (of course) you can always `cd`.  You can provide full or relative paths to any file.  In general you should not assume what the current directory is and supply path names where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `run.sh` which does the required processing on one text file at a time, the following command will keep 4 parallel bash sessions alive:

```
find -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -n 1 -P 4 -0 -I {} bash run.sh {}
```

From `man xargs`:

```
--max-procs=max-procs, -P max-procs
      Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.
      If max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time. 
      Use the -n option with -P; otherwise chances are that only one exec will be done.
```